# Flags declined in the last 7 days...not?

Tags: support, bug, flagging

So, I was going about my business on Worldbuilding today, when I tried to flag a post and found myself under a flag ban.  While I was under a flag-ban previously, it had expired a few days earlier.  I went to check which of my flags had been declined and found that none of them had.  Instead, I found that apparently a flag declined on July 2nd was one of my declined flags for the last 7 days.

[image: Image was taken today, July 12th]

Given that it is currently July 12th, and a flag declined 10 days ago is not the same thing as a flag declined in the last 7 days, this makes little sense to me.  Is this a bug, or a feature of some kind I was unaware of, or what?

Comment: I count 3/13 flags declined in the last 7 days; 25% of flags declined [*should* set off the flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/274942). So . . . this is kind of close to that; maybe a script ran before the last flag was handled? Note that the date a flag was cast doesn't matter; the date it was *handled* does matter.

Comment: @HDE226868 the problem here is that one of the flags counted as "declined in the last 7 days" was declined 10 days ago.

Comment: Where does it tell you that? The one from July 2 was handled on July 7, 5 days ago.

Comment: Just for reference, the above info *is* available to normal users - mouse over the status of a handled flag e.g. the "helpful" or "declined" bit. I've tested this out on other sites that I don't mod. You just can't see that info for other users.

Comment: Yes, I simply hadn't realized that it was.

Comment: Sorry I apparently steered you wrong on your previous meta question.  I thought it went by the dates you raised the flags, not the dates they were handled.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It was a perfectly reasonable assumption, and not in any way your fault.  Thanks for attempting to help me, even if neither of us had all the information we would have liked at the time.